# How to change syslog tag or use my custom tag in rsyslog?

Tags: templates, syslog, rsyslog

How do I change default syslogtag like "propname[pid]" to my own label in order to distinguish log from different equipment?

I want to collect log from different equipment to a log server. I need to distinguish them by some unique tag like MAC address or serial number other than IP address (may change with network) or hostname (may be same for all equip). How can I add these labels as property or tag into the log?

Comment: Ever figure this out?